# Setting and keeping MemoryCache when loading Razorpages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, memorycache, razor-pages

I am trying to add a bounch of lists into the MemoryCache when a razorpage loads.
The lists are added to the cache but seem to get lost when I reload the page

what am I doing wrong here? have I missunderstood how the cache works?

Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddMemoryCache();
        }
```

Razorpage constructor

```
private IMemoryCache _cache;    
public TimesModel(IMemoryCache memoryCache){
_cache = memoryCache;
}
```

Razorpage ongetAsync

```
public async Task OnGetAsync() {
if (_cache.Get<List<CommonListTable>>("listR2") == null) {
                _sqlLoads++;
                _cache.Set("listR2", CommonData.listR2, cacheEntryOptions);
     }
}
```

thanks

Thomas

Comment: What cacheEntryOptions are you specifying?

Comment: I am using , var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)); but havn't really looked in to the differnent options. good tip

Comment: 3 seconds is not leaving yourself much time to check, maybe set it to a longer interval for testing purposes and see if it's still there after a reload.